# Ruby の class_eval、class_exec にブロック、Proc、lambda を渡すときの違いについて

Tags: ruby

class_eval, class_exec で 次のような結果になります。(instance_xxxでも同様)

```
class Foo
  def self.abc
    puts 'abc'
  end
end

aa = lambda { abc }
bb = proc { abc }


Foo.class_eval { abc }
> abc    <= OK        

Foo.class_eval &aa
> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)  <= NG!!

Foo.class_eval &bb
> abc  <= OK!!

Foo.class_exec &aa
> abc  <= OK!!

Foo.class_exec &bb
> abc  <= OK!!
```

lambda を class_eval で 渡したときに ArgumentError がでてしまいます。
class_exec を使えば問題ないのですが、なぜ、class_eval と lambda の組み合わせの場合に、ArgumentErrorが発生するのでしょうか？？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lambdaは引数の扱いが厳密です。

> lambda のほうがより厳密です。引数の数が違っていると（メソッドのように）エラーになります。 Proc.new は引数を多重代入に近い扱い方をします。
>   https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Kernel/m/lambda.html

引数を取らないlambdaに引数を与えて呼び出すとエラーになります。

```
irb(main):001:0> lambda { }.call(:error)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
    from (irb):1:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Foo.class_evalの場合ブロックの引数としてFooを渡します。
https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Module/i/class_eval.html

lambdaは引数の扱いが厳密なのでclass_evalに引数なしのlambdaをブロックとして渡すと、Fooを引数に渡そうとしてArgumentErrorになります。
例えば以下のように、引数を1つ取るようなlambdaをブロックとして渡した場合はlambdaでもエラーが出ません。

```
aa = lambda { |mod| abc }
Foo.class_eval(&aa)
```

Comment: とてもわかり易く理解できました。 `XX_eval` 系にブロックを渡すときは必ずレシーバのオブジェクトがブロック引数として渡され、 `XX_exec`系 は必要に応じて自分で引数を指定できるから指定しなければ引数が渡されないのでlamdaでも問題ないということですね。